# Auto-install using apt-get or yum

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, package-management, apt-get

On my Ubuntu machine, if I don't have a particular application installed, the message often points me to the correct package.

Example:

```
$ rz
The program 'rz' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install lrzsz
```

Is there any way to automate the invocation to install, so that my shell will execute `sudo apt-get install ....` on its own if such a situation arises?

Alternatively, is there a shortcut so that the entire `sudo a ... sz` command doesn't have to be typed/copied in?

To clarify:
[This related solution](//superuser.com/questions/367454/change-the-ubuntu-program-that-runs-when-a-command-cant-be-found) does not meet the requirements because:

1. This fails for the example above. `lrzsz` is the package but `rz` is the application. `apt` tells me the right package to install; I don't want to use `$1`. This would apply for `java` etc. too....
2. It can get quite irritating in practice as it offers to install my typos; e.g., if I type `ptyhon` instead of `python`:

   ```
   $ ptyhon
   Do you want to install ptyhon? [N/y] y
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   E: Unable to locate package ptyhon
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the Ubuntu program that runs when a command can't be found](http://superuser.com/questions/367454/change-the-ubuntu-program-that-runs-when-a-command-cant-be-found).  Related: [How does Ubuntu know what programs exist and can be installed?](http://superuser.com/questions/618609/how-does-ubuntu-know-what-programs-exist-and-can-be-installed)

Comment: The other post helps but it only allows me to use `$1` as the package_name to install. I'm trying to make it work for the example above, where the package to install is different from the command.

Comment: `$1` is not the name of the package, but reference to it. I don't see why the proposed solution wouldn't work for you. Please explain it by editing your question.

Comment: Thanks @MátéJuhász. Hope the edit above explains what I'm looking to do.

Comment: See [Hook into “command not found” handler in Ubuntu](/q/787424/150988), [How do I stop my bash shell from asking to install a package?](/q/641365/150988), [How to search for a package with pacman?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/297877/23408), [In Arch Linux, how can I find out which package to install that will contain file *X*?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/14858/23408), and [Falling to git checkout on non-found bash commands](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131272/23408). But also: why is copying from the error message (e.g., with your mouse) and pasting into the command line unacceptable?